# Why I can't call max function in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

After allocating an array in the heap.I'm trying to make a function max to find the biggest number in an array with pointers, but it gives me this error:-In function ‘int main()’:
error:max,cannot be used as a function.
  Here is the code:

```
     #include<iostream>
     using namespace std;

    int max(int *v,int n){
       int i,max=0;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(*(v+i)>max)
                max=v[i];
        } 
        return max;
    }

     int main(){
     int *v,n,i;

  //read n    
     cout<<"Number of elements  ";
     cin>>n;

     v = new int[n];

    //read elements
    cout<<"Array Ellements:";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cin>>v[i];
    }

    // output array elements   
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cout<<v[i];
        if(i<n)
        cout<<",";

    }
    cout<<endl;

     //max store the biggest number in the array
     int max;
     max = max(v,n);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `using namespace std;`  There's half your problem right there.

Comment: `max = ::max( v, n );` should work

Comment: @cHao That's a problem, but it's not the cause of the problem this question is asking about. Notably `max(int*, int)` isn't ambiguous with `std::max`.

Comment: `int max;` hides `int max(int*, int)`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It certainly isn't helping. OP literally has half a dozen things floating around with the name `max`.

Comment: @cHao It's not helping, and it's certainly a bad habit, but it's not the source of *this* problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  "but it's not the source of this problem" and that is not an answer either but comment.

Comment: This is not exact duplicate though, unlike C++ in C it is not possible to refer to the function as `::max()`

Comment: There is no point to reimplement the wheel every time, you better use `std::max_element()` in this case

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers and contribution :3; problem solved!

Comment: @AndreiRazmerita you should accept the answer that solved your problem

Comment: @bolov sure, I am kinda new here,so I did't know I had to press the check mark :P

Comment: I stared because this is a perfect example of why not use `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot have a function and variable with the same name active in the same scope and use both of them. So this can never work (as you discovered)

```
int max;
max = max(v,n); // the word 'max' now refers to the variable called 'max' not the function
```

Do

```
int maxValue = max(v,n);
```

Comment: well... you can have both. But in his case the local variable hides the function.

Comment: As a general statement, it is wrong. You certainly CAN have a variable and a function with the same name.

Comment: for a CS100 level question my answer is correct, but I will tweks it slightly

Comment: IT worked, as u commented, I changed the variable max in main and function worked well, thank you, I can't believed, what a ridiculous error to debug.

Comment: @AndreiRazmerita just don't use `using namespace std;` your coding habits will get better.

Comment: @Sailanarmo Well, I did a lot of C last year (CS degree), I just started this new course of C++,this week, in the next months I will study OOP(C++), but I already know the concepts from Java, thanks for the tip, I will take in consideration your suggestion!